# How to Create a Trigger to prevent a connected app from Enriching account

Tags: apex, trigger, validation-rule

Part of my question is also whether creating a trigger is the way to go or if there is an alternate or easier way...

Here's the situation - there is a 3rd party integration with a data set that automatically matches new accounts to the data then populates/enriches the data in Salesforce.

I would like to know how I can fire off a check based on a field before the app is triggered or at least before it makes changes.

For example, if an account has a custom field that labels what type of company it is, e.g. `INC` or `LLC` , I only want to prevent it from running the match and sync on ones that are labeled as `LLC`.

So if its `INC` it can do what it usually does, but if it is an `LLC` then I would like the app to ignore it and not run any enrichment checks.

Comment: It will all depend on how the app works. If it does not allow you to set a setting, filter , or otherwise hook into its behavior then you can't. Your best bet is to reach out to the publisher and speak with them

Comment: If you are the publisher provide s custom setting or something where they can specify a filter clause or some similar approach